# Can I retain quickmarks (not bookmarks) in Zathura after closing?

Tags: zathura

I recently discovered Zathura, and like it quite a bit. In particular, I like that I can use "quickmarks" as in vim. That is, by just pressing e.g. `ma`, I can create the quickmark `a`, to which I can then jump by pressing `'a`.

However, whenever I close Zathura, all my quickmarks get lost. In contrast, the "bookmarks" (created with `:bmark`, and viewed using `:blist`) are retained after closing and reopening a file (side note: Do you know where these are saved?). However, I don't really like the bookmarks, since there does not seem to be an easy way to jump to them (or is there?).

> I was wondering if there is any possibility of retaining the *quickmarks* as well after closing Zathura, since I find them much more convenient to use than the actual bookmarks.

Comment: I hope this question gets more attention. Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: @Student: Sadly no. But I discovered Sioyek which is somehow similar to Zathura. Sioyek does save quickmarks. I use both at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

In linux,  ***Zathura*** stores bookmarks in the following file:

> /home/user/.local/share/zathura/bookmarks

***Zathura*** stores quickmarks in the following file:

> /home/user/.local/share/zathura/history

in this history file quickmarks are saved as jumplilst. Sorry your specific quickmark letters aren't saved in Zathura. You will lose them when you close the document. But your jumping places of that file is saved. And you can use *ctrl+o , ctrl+i* to jump between places even after closing and opening the document.

You can edit bookmarks, history file and you can carry them with you, so you don't loose your bookmarks and documents settings ever. If your file path or drive letters changes when you move your documents or switch computers, then you should change the file path in the bookmarks file. So that you'll get the same bookmarks, settings everywhere.

In this way,

### Zathura is portable too.